# multiple attribution with linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I’m working on a problem that is analyzing purchases at a store and determining the effect from advertising. There are many advertising variables, but to keep things simple, assume there are three types of media:

```
Television, desktop, mobile
```

four types of creatives (ad speak for advertisement type):

```
tv_crt_A, tv_crt_B, digital_crt_A, digital_crt_B
```

two types of tv shows:

```
tv_A and tv_B
```

two types of websites:

```
web_A and web_B
```

The independent variables are

```
Television, Desktop, mobile tv_crt_A, tv_crt_B, digital_crt_A, digital_crt_B, tv_A, tv_B, web_A, web_B
```

Each time an ad is served to a given person they may have any combination of the above. For Example, on October 1, person p _1 may be servered with an ad with the following attributes:

```
Vector_1=0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

This equates to person_1 being served an add on desktop with digital_ctr_B on web_B. Count the number of purchases that this person makes before getting another ad ( they may only get one ad). If they do not purchase before they receive another ad they receive a 0. For example, 4 days later they receive another ad of the form

```
0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
```

so person p_1 was served an ad on oct 5 on mobile, with digital_ctr_B on web_A. There is a cumulative effect to advertising, so this exposure takes the form of

```
vector_2= 0,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1
```

meaning that they have now been served an ad on desktop and mobile, and seen digital_ctr_B twice, once on web_A and once on web_B.

Again, count all the purchases they make before they receive their next ad exposure.

Since this is sensitive the time between exposures I thought about modeling the problem as the average purchases per day between exposures.  For example if person p_1 made a purchase on oct 2 and oct 3, then we would have y= 2(purcahses)/4(days)=.5

Could I get the coefficients for each variable and then for each purchase divide each unique coefficient-variable product by the sum of the coefficient-variable product for that exposure. Suppose the coefficients for the variables are

```
Television =.10
Desktop =.041
Mobile = .0352
tv_crt_A =.078
tv_crt_B = .119
digital_crt_A =.002
digital_crt_B =.047
tv_A =.043
tv_B= .021
web_A =.037
web_B = .081
```

For the two purchases in vector_1 I would get a contribution for

```
Desktop = (1*(.041))/(1*.041 + 1*.047+ 1*.081)
digital_crt_B=  (1*(.047))/(1*.041 + 1*.047+ 1*.081)
web_B= (1*(.081))/(1*.041 + 1*.047+ 1*.081)
```

All other variables would  have zero contribution for this purchase.

Suppose there was 1 purchase for vector_2. I would get contributions of

```
Desktop = (1*(.041))/ (1*.041 + 1*(.0352) + 2*.047+ 1*.037 + 1*.081)
Mobile=(1*(.0352))/ ))/ (1*.041 + 1*(.0352) + 2*.047+ 1*.037 + 1*.081)
digital_crt_B=  (2*(.047))/  (1*.041 + 1*(.0352) + 2*.047+ 1*.037 + 1*.081)
```

web_A= (1*(.037))/  (1*.041 + 1*(.0352) + 2*.047+ 1*.037 + 1*.081)
   web_B= (1*(.081))/  (1*.041 + 1*(.0352) + 2*.047+ 1*.037 + 1*.081)

All other variables would have zero contribution for the purchase.

A could make this a binary outcome, “purchased” or “not purchased” and use logistic regression, but I thought this approach would give a more granular view.

Is this a sound approach?

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to read if it was rephrased to use equations with defined variables, rather than trying to describe the math in words and then substituting in numbers.

Comment: I think it would be great if we could consider time after the ad as a decaying constant. Like If that person bought an item just after the ad is displayed, the impact of that ad is very high compared to the ad that he saw last week. I think we must consider that as a feature of interest. Just a thought.